# SQL Server Group By Bitwise Or?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, bit-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Aggregate bitwise-OR in a subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981050/aggregate-bitwise-or-in-a-subquery)
>   [Update column to be different aggregate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112382/update-column-to-be-different-aggregate-values)

Let's say I have a table with the following records.

```
Role | AuthorizationNum

1      11
2      12
1      16
2      11
```

What I want to do is group by Role, the OR (BIT OR using |) AuthorizationNum.  So my select should be 2 records.

```
Role | AuthorizationNum

1      27
2      15
```

Because...

11 | 16 = 27

11 | 12 = 15

Comment: do u need the sum of the authorizationNum grouped by roleID?

Comment: You want to use bitwise or as an aggregate function? If so this is a dupe... Just trying to find it.

Comment: @Martin here is the duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112382/update-column-to-be-different-aggregate-values

Answer (score 0):

By default mysql supports this but not sql server.
But you can get around it using this: [Update column to be different aggregate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112382/update-column-to-be-different-aggregate-values)

Comment: Now I understand what he meant. Sorry for the confustion